# Devexpress GridView Selected Column visible= false, But didnt display after gridviewexporter download

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, devexpress

I am using devexpress and i want to set the selected gridview column visible = false, but i want that to appear on my csv as other name but with hyperlink on it after devexpress gridviewexporter download.

here is my code

```
<dx:ASPxButton ID="FeedbackGridBut" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" OnClick="FeedbackGridBut_Click" Text="Download" Image-Url="../images/excel.png"></dx:ASPxButton>

<dx:ASPxGridViewExporter GridViewID="FeedbackGrid" ID="exportFeedbackGrid" runat="server"></dx:ASPxGridViewExporter>
                            <dx:ASPxGridView ID="FeedbackGrid" ClientIDMode="Static" OnCustomUnboundColumnData="FeedbackGrid_CustomUnboundColumnData" ClientInstanceName="FeedbackGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="table table-striped" SettingsPager-Mode="ShowAllRecords" SettingsSearchPanel-Visible="True" DataSourceID="FeedbackDatasource" EnableCallBacks="true" SettingsBehavior-ProcessSelectionChangedOnServer="true" EnableRowsCache="False" SettingsBehavior-AutoExpandAllGroups="true" SettingsPopup-HeaderFilter-Height="400">
                                <Columns>
                                    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="sno" Visible="false">                                  
                                    </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
</Columns>
</dx:ASPxGridView>
```

vb.net

```
 Protected Sub FeedbackGridBut_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        exportFeedbackGrid.WriteXlsToResponse()
    End Sub
```

when i pressed the download all the column appeared except for the sno column, i dont want sno to appear on the webpage, i just want it to appear on the downloaded csv as other name as the sno value is too long and messy( for example: one of the value is asjdkgskfg-asdasd-asdasdasd) with hyperlink but it is not working.

Comment: Export the source data, not the GridView contents. And what is happening in `exportFeedbackGrid.WriteXlsToResponse()`?

Comment: but my gridview content is linked with the source data and exportFeedbackGrid.WriteXlsToResponse() is to export whatever data appeared on the gridview webpage

Comment: But why not export that data directly without using the GridView? Then you have full control over the data.

Comment: wait, seems like there is mistake on my question, i reedit the question.

Comment: done editing, do you have any idea on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ASPxGridViewExporter` by default will export columns depending on current grid's condition, including hidden columns. If you want to show hidden columns, just set their visibility immediately before using `WriteXlsToResponse()` method:

```
Protected Sub FeedbackGridBut_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    exportFeedbackGrid.Columns("sno").Visible = True ' Set column state to visible
    ' Optional: exportFeedbackGrid.DataBind()
    exportFeedbackGrid.WriteXlsToResponse()
End Sub
```

The actual grid object will not changed because the grid properties has changed when triggers postback to return file.

References:

[ASPxGridViewExporter - How to export hidden columns?](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q315330/aspxgridviewexporter-how-to-export-hidden-columns)

[ASPxGridViewExporter - How to hide column during export](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T172586/aspxgridviewexporter-how-to-hide-column-during-export) (opposite from above)

Comment: sorry but i have another problem, is there any control for devexpress gridviewexporter to export xls with hyperlink? for example each of the columns("sno").value with hyperlink. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can see [this reference](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q555935/aspxgridview-export-excel-with-hyperlink-field-issue), it suggested that you should use `GridViewDataHyperLinkColumn` for `sno` column.